# Ruby on rails and JQuery-datatables with TableTools. Saving all pages of the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

I am using JQuery-datatables for my model Contacts and apply for this [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/). I have provided several buttons for datatable, but it saves only one page instead of saving all my table. In [Examples](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/examples) I have studied everything seems OK with saving all the table.

Here is my contacts.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
$.extend $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses,
  sSortAsc: "header headerSortDown"
  sSortDesc: "header headerSortUp"
  sSortable: "header"

$('#contacts').dataTable
  sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
  bJQueryUI: true
  bProcessing: true
  bServerSide: true
  sAjaxSource: $('#contacts').data('source')
  sDom: "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>"
    oTableTools:
      sSwfPath: "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
      aButtons: [
        sExtends: "copy"
        sButtonText: "Copy to clipboard",

        sExtends: "csv"
        sButtonText: "Save to CSV",

        sExtends: "xls"
        sButtonText: "Save for Excel"
        ]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: On page on pdf or what? csv and exel are kinda pageless :)

Comment: There are implemented "bootstrap" pagination (sPaginationType: "bootstrap" in my contacts.js.coffee)

Comment: forget my comments, was stupid... had no clue from dataTables and was confused :) Still checking on it